# Suppose $X \sim \chi^2(n)$. How can I prove that there exist $Z_i \sim N(0,1)$ independent such that $X = \sum_{i=1}^n Z_i^2$?

Tags: probability-theory, probability-distributions

In general, knowing the distribution of a random variable $X$ is not the same as knowing the explicit mapping from $\Omega$ to $\mathbb{R}$. Suppose then that $X \sim \chi^2(n)$. I know that the distribution of $X$ is the same as the distribution of a sum of squares of independent standard normals, but how can I show that there exist $Z_1, \cdots, Z_n$ such that $X = \sum_{i=1}^n Z_i^2$? Don't I have to know something about the underlying probability space to make this claim?

Comment: first, how you define the equality "$=$" in the statement  $X = \sum_{i=1}^n Z_i^2$? In law?

Comment: @NN2 They must be pointwise equal.